# Drawing a Picture to a View's Canvas does nothing

Tags: android, view, image

I'm trying to use `android.graphics.Picture` to speed up some drawing my application does. However, when I try to replay it, nothing happens, it's as if either the `Picture` simply isn't drawn or as if it did not record anything.

Here's my drawing code; for simplicity, I just moved everything inside my `View`'s `onDraw` method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

    Picture p = new Picture();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    Canvas c = p.beginRecording(100, 100);
    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
    p.endRecording();

    p.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPicture(p);
}
```

With this, all I get is a completely red background, nothing else; neither the line nor the `Picture`'s white background shows up.

I then tried the example code posted at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/DrawPicture.htm, also to no avail: nothing shows, all I get is a white background.

This happens on both my Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2) and the Emulator (4.2.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your Activity:

```
View view = new View(this);
Picture picture = new Picture();
Canvas c = picture.beginRecording(100, 100);
Paint p = new Paint();
c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
p.setColor(Color.RED);
c.drawCircle(50, 50, 40, p);
picture.endRecording();
Drawable d = new PictureDrawable(picture);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
setContentView(view);
```

you should see small red circle on the white background (tested on 2.3 emulator)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I completely missed this answer :).